# Dymanic Controls C# Accessing without Name property

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have a panel, where my program is adding dynamic controls. Either I want to access these controls at runtime for changing their colors or texts.

the only way I know is:

```
Control [] myControls = myPanel.Controls.Find( name , true );
```

Here the problem is, my dynamic Controls have not any name ! Their name are " null ".
If I'm trying name as a null value, it gives error. How can I achieve it ? Must I give
every added control a name ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Why do you need to distinguish the controls apart from each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could just do something like this:

```
foreach(Control control in myPanel.Controls)
  control.Backcolor=Color.Black;
```

Comment: thanks it's working. Should I use .GetType to learn the kind of my Control if it is a button or a label or something else ?

Comment: You can du a "if (control is Button) { ((Button)control).blahblahblah; } else if (control is label) { (((Label)control).blah_blah_blah"; }

etc....

Comment: Yes, the `is` operator tests if a class is a subclass of another class, or in this case if your actual instance is of a more specific class than just a generic `Control`.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the Controls collection:

```
 foreach(var control in myPanel.Controls) {

    //Here you do something with the appropriate control.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just keep a reference (e.g. instance field, within a dictionary, etc.) to each dynamically added control, and use this when you'll need to access the controls later.